# Source code protection at Microsoft

Tags: source-code-protection

Here's another question about source code protection... So far I haven't been convinced with the answers to similar questions found on this site (NDAs on the legal side, trusting employees vs. protected code, etc.) So I'd like to formulate it in a different manner:

How do large companies do to protect their source code? E.g. I have never heard that the Windows, MS-DOS source code was ever stolen, reverse engineered? What steps does a large company like Microsoft take to protect their code?

Comment: Actually Windows NT & 2K source code leaked: http://www.neowin.net/news/exclusive-windows-2000--windows-nt-4-source-code-leaks

Answer (score 12):

One very important factor is that working with complex source code requires solid domain knowledge. So complex code  becomes largely useless without the people that wrote it. Even if some third party steals all the code it will likely be unable to make alterations to it or use it.

One good example is [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) - all its code is public domain and published. How much time will someone without solid knowledge of its inner workings need to make any alterations or analysis of that code? And SQLite is not a very big piece of software. Yet people developing it support it and publish updates all the time.

Comment: Yes. At one of the companies I've worked for, we joked the best way to set our competitors back several years would be to give them our source code...

Comment: @Paul - Why not release it under an open-source license then? Does it make sense to think that a piece of source code could give an advantage to the competition?

Comment: As I said, it was a joke. There would be bits of it that did give competitive advantage away. But if someone's going to compile the code, they can steal it. The only thing you can do is restrict code to what they need to work on/see  (but that's usually most of any product), not let them see products they're not working on, and cover yourself with NDAs and contracts. There really is nothing else

Comment: So you would think that Microsoft doesn't use any other methods?

Comment: @ericdes: Releasing under an open-source license is another deal. When you do it you say "Hey, people, enjoy our code - study and modify it" and people can do that and that won't be a law violaion. When your code is not published it is fully protected by copyright so doing anything with it is *illegal* which means that under certain conditions abusers can face liability. You see? The difference is like having or not having a "The street should be crossed here" sign - the street can be crosses both with the sign or without, but with the sign there's a permission.

Answer (score 8):

> I have never heard that the Windows,
>   MS-DOS source code was ever stolen,
>   reverse engineered?

Well, than you haven't been listening very carefully. Reverse engineering Microsoft's operating system code happens all the time. Go read books like "Undocumented Windows 2000 Secrets: A Programmer's Cookbook" or "Windows NT/2000 Native API Reference" by Gary Nebbet.
Or remember what Cogswell and Russinovich did before being bought by Microsoft.

Also, around 6 years ago, (parts of) the source code of Windows 2000 was leaked:

http://www.wired.com/science/discoveries/news/2004/02/62282

Answer (score 6):

First, they pay enough and have big enough legal and security teams to make it not worth it for most employees to think of taking the risk of leaking it. Second, they limit the access to their source control systems based on the portions of the codebase that particular developers need access to.

Comment: It looks like a good answer to me, as far as how they protect leaking from the inside... But is it really all? Don't they have anything else worth knowing about?

Comment: Sure they do, but what kind of value would a thief get from it? They'd either get an older version of the software, which would take at least months to understand and get building correctly, or they'd get a version with features in various states of brokenness in the middle of development. As for reverse engineering, the amount of code makes this a cost-prohibitive exercise, especially when the compiled code is heavily optimized.